Handling Square Terminal Transactions with Webhooks
I'm relatively new to working with webhooks and I'm currently integrating Square Terminal transactions into my web application. Specifically, I'm trying to implement a workflow where I can display a spinner while initiating the checkout using the Square Terminal API, and then hide the spinner upon receiving a webhook event indicating the completion of the payment.
Here's the workflow I'm trying to achieve:

When a user clicks the "Pay Now" button on my web application, I
want to display a spinner to indicate that the payment is being
processed. Upon clicking the button, I make a call to the Square
Terminal API to initiate the checkout. Once the checkout initiation
is successful, I receive a checkout ID from the API response.
While waiting for the payment to be completed, I continue to display the
spinner.
When the payment is completed and I receive a webhook event
indicating the success of the transaction, I want to hide the
spinner and display a confirmation message to the user.

I'm struggling to implement this workflow efficiently, especially regarding how to handle the spinner display during the checkout initiation and webhook event processing. Can someone provide guidance on how to structure this workflow effectively? Any code examples or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

The webhook request has no direct connection to your frontend - it is a request made by their servers, to your server. So you will either need to create some kind of polling script on the client side that periodically checks with the server, or something to "push" the info from the server, to the relevant client (something using websockets, or similar.)
